# SSIS Custom Component: Accessing Variables during Design Time

Tags: ssis

I am trying to read a package variable during design-time. I am able to do it during run-time fairly easily:

```
IDTSVariables variables = null;
pipelineComponent.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("MyVariable");
pipelineComponent.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(out variables);
```

But during design-time, I don't have a PipelineComponent and I can't find any object that will give me a VariableDispenser.

I've looked at the IDtsVariableService class, but it appears to only provide a helper UI to facilitate the creation of new variables -- I want to read an existing variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was close, it was the IDtsPipelineEnvironmentService class:

```
Variables vars = null;

IDtsPipelineEnvironmentService pipelineService = (IDtsPipelineEnvironmentService)serviceProvider_.GetService(typeof(IDtsPipelineEnvironmentService));
pipelineService.PipelineTaskHost.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("VARIABLE_NAME");
pipelineService.PipelineTaskHost.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);
VARIABLE = vars[0].Value.ToString();
vars.Unlock();
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the following link might help you.

- [**Accessing Variables in SSIS code**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/5660a3a1-0906-49b3-a22b-688c56a6a872/)